# Magento 2.1 adjusting memory_limit on shared hosting

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7

I have Magento 2.1.3 setup on Godaddy shared hosting and after much struggling around with php.ini files, the web host has decided that Magento is showing the global memory limit (512MB) on the server rather than the local memory limit (2048MB). Obviously, the host is unwilling to change the global memory limit, so my question here is how can I force Magento to look at the local php.ini file within my hosting? If it is not possible, please suggest me another way to proceed.

Comment: which web server your application is using (apache/nginx) ?

Comment: I am using apache server

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it for you Magento installation on a shared server just edit the

> app/bootstrap.php

Just add a line underneath (line 11):

> #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

with the setting you want to change for example:

> ini_set('memory_limit', 2048MB);